# Deploying multiple WARS into Tomcat Using Maven

Tags: maven

I have two applications and want to deploy these two WARS into tomcat 7.0 using maven. I tried to see all posts of Stackoverflow regarding this and modeled my POM accordingly. However, while running the parent POM, I noticed that only the first application(RestApp) is getting deployed not the second app. Could you please see if there is some correction required in POM

Parent POM

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org    /2001/XMLSchema-     instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>my.parent</groupId>
<artifactId>ParentProj</artifactId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<version>1.0</version>
<name>Parent Maven Webapp</name>
<!-- <url>http://maven.apache.org</url> -->
<properties>

    <!--Test -->
    <project.build.finalName>ParentProj</project.build.finalName>
</properties>

<modules>
    <module>RESTApp</module>
    <module>WebIntegrationApp</module>
</modules>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.8.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>


</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>${project.build.finalName}</finalName>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                 <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                 <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                 <version>2.6</version>
            </plugin>
             <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                  <version>2.4</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
                <artifactId>cargo-maven2-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.3</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.16</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.16</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>deploy</id>
                        <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>

                <configuration>
                    <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>

</build>

</project>
```

Here is the child Apps

```
RestApp

   <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org     /2001/XMLSchema-     instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-              v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>my.parent</groupId>
    <artifactId>ParentProj</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <relativePath>../</relativePath>
</parent>
    <artifactId>RestApp</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

  <properties>

    <!--Test -->
    <project.build.finalName>RestApp</project.build.finalName>
</properties>

<dependencies>


</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jetty-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.25</version>
        </plugin>


        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

```
   WebIntegrationApp

  <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-    instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-    4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<parent>
    <groupId>my.parent</groupId>
    <artifactId>ParentProj</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <relativePath>../</relativePath>
</parent>
<artifactId>WebIntegrationApp</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<properties>

    <!--Test -->
    <project.build.finalName>WebIntegrationApp</project.build.finalName>
</properties>

<dependencies>


</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jetty-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.25</version>
        </plugin>


        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <webappDirectory>${project.build.directory}/tmp</webappDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: this seems to be wrong: <webappDirectory>${project.build.directory}/tmp</webappDirectory> - I think you can remove it?

Comment: Its not working on removing this as well. The application which is added first to <modules> tag is loaded and deployed into server. I confirmed this on swapping the apps on module tags.

Comment: You should configure `cargo` in each submodule, I think.

Comment: well there is the tomcat7-maven-plugin in the parent. but it is inside pluginManagement, that means those are only defaults. you need to add that into plugins as well. that plugin is also configured for WebContent, that is the ecplise default folder but not the maven default.

Comment: Can you please explain more on this statement- "that plugin is also configured for WebContent, that is the ecplise default folder but not the maven default."